# when I every refresh page load button_click events run too

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have code Page_Load and btnGonder_Click.I records the some data to database when I click the btnGonder.And I get and show data in the datalist the code which inside the page_load.The problem is that  When I every refresh the page,it runs btn_Gonder_Click events and so it records the same data to database.my code is below.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!IsPostBack)
{
        Cevap cevaplar = new Cevap();
        int soru_id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Soru_Id"]);
        cevaplar.soru_id = soru_id;
        DataTable dtcvp = new DataTable();
        dtcvp = cevaplar.Cevaplarive_CevapVerenleri_Getir();
        datalistcevaplar.DataSource = dtcvp;
        datalistcevaplar.DataBind();
}
}

 protected void btnGonder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Users kullanicim = new Users();
        HttpCookie bilgiler = Request.Cookies["Kullanicicookie"];
        kullanicim.mail = bilgiler["mail"];
        int donenkullaniciid = kullanicim.Kullanici_Id_Donder();
        cevaplar.cvpveren_id = donenkullaniciid;
        Sorular sorular = new Sorular();
        sorular.Cevap_Sayisi_Artir(soru_id);
        bool durum = cevaplar.Cevap_Ekle();
        if (durum)
        {
            lblDurum.Text = "Cevabınız Eklenmiştir";
        }
        else
        {
            lblDurum.Text = "Cevabınız Eklenmemiştir";
        }
        DataTable dtcvp = new DataTable();
        dtcvp = cevaplar.Cevaplarive_CevapVerenleri_Getir();
        datalistcevaplar.DataSource = dtcvp;
        datalistcevaplar.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page refresh re-fires the same event which has caused the previous postback , so if you refresh the page after clicking the button then button click event will fire. Now to avoid that you have gor multiple solutions. see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/175832/Avoid-button-click-event-on-page-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

Use this.IsPostBack inside btnGonder_Click() to check the status of submission and return

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to resubmit the page on refresh then from btnGonder_Click you need to redirect to the same page instead of directly binding data. As this is the basic problem with the Asp.net application.

Do Response.Redirect and pass the name of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already clicked on a button which caused a post back. Next onwards pressing F5, the browser will ask you RESEND which means click the button again. This is normal browser behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a workaround to check if it is a page refresh or an actual  button click. You can do as below:
The key here is `ViewState["IsPageRefresh"]` & `Session["IsPageRefresh"]`.  Note that ViewState needs to be enabled on the page for this to work; if ViewState is not enabled then a hidden field may be used.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
Session["IsPageRefresh"] = Server.UrlDecode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ViewState["IsPageRefresh"] = Session["IsPageRefresh"];
}
protected void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (Session["IsPageRefresh"].ToString() == ViewState["IsPageRefresh"].ToString())
{
//Put your database INSERT code here
Session["IsPageRefresh"] = Server.UrlDecode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
}
```

**One simple trick but may be not a standard practice**  I too agree is below:
Don’t disable the button in the server side. After the page has finished  loading the button works as usual.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkButton() {
            var btn = document.getElementById("btnGonder");
            btn.disabled = true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnGonder" runat="server" onclick="btnGonder_Click" 
         OnClientClick="checkButton();" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```